# Finding a change of measure so that rescaled local martingale is a local martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $\mu,\sigma:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be deterministic continuous functions, assume that $\sigma$ is bounded below by a strictly positive constant and that $\mu$ has compact support. Suppose that $X$ is a solution to the SDE $$dX_t=X_t(\mu(t)dt+\sigma(t)dB_t)$$ with $X_0=1$ with respect to the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.

The first part of the question, which I have completed, was to show that $X_te^{-\int_0^t\mu(s)ds}$ is a local martingale under $\mathbb{P}$, which is a fairly simple consequence of Ito's formula. The second question asks me to find a probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ under which $X_t$ is a local martingale. (I think) the only results regarding change of measure in my lecture course have been Girsanov's theorem, but I can't see this directly as an application of Girsanov's theorem, so I am stuck. Hints and advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint: Find a measure $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$ such that $\tilde W_t$ defined by $d\tilde W_t := \mu(t)dt + \sigma(t)dB_t$ is a martingale under $\tilde{\mathbb{P}}$

Comment: Hi - thanks for the hint! I think I see why this would lead to the result (because then we have $dX_t=X_td\tilde{W}_t$ is a local martingale, but I still am not sure how to get to the measure. Could you possibly elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Following from the above hint. We have that $ dX_t = \sigma(t) X_t \left(dB_t + \frac{\mu_t}{\sigma_t}dt \right)$. Can you apply the Cameron-Martin theorem here?